# Process State replication

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, procfs, memory-mapping

I Need to create process state replication between two processes.
I am using a simple bash script that count to infinity.

I am running it on server 1 and server 2 and making the process on server 2 always paused and i need to copy the state (memory) from the first process to the second one (the replica).

I am very familar with procfs and I know that the memory pages contains the state in memory page as follows:

```
root@ubuntu:/proc/41932# cat maps 
7f7254d85000-7f7254f40000 r-xp 00000000 00:27 30                         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f7254f40000-7f725513f000 ---p 001bb000 00:27 30                         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f725513f000-7f7255143000 r--p 001ba000 00:27 30                         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f7255143000-7f7255145000 rw-p 001be000 00:27 30                         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f7255145000-7f725514a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f725514a000-7f725516d000 r-xp 00000000 00:27 27                         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f7255364000-7f7255367000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f725536a000-7f725536c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f725536c000-7f725536d000 r--p 00022000 00:27 27                         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f725536d000-7f725536e000 rw-p 00023000 00:27 27                         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f725536e000-7f725536f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f725536f000-7f725538b000 r-xp 00000000 00:27 22                         /bin/dash
7f725558a000-7f725558c000 r--p 0001b000 00:27 22                         /bin/dash
7f725558c000-7f725558d000 rw-p 0001d000 00:27 22                         /bin/dash
7f725558d000-7f725558f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7256799000-7f72567ba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fff06be2000-7fff06c03000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff06cb8000-7fff06cba000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7fff06cba000-7fff06cbc000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
root@ubuntu:/proc/41932# ls map_files/
7f7254d85000-7f7254f40000  7f725513f000-7f7255143000  7f725514a000-7f725516d000  7f725536d000-7f725536e000  7f725558a000-7f725558c000
7f7254f40000-7f725513f000  7f7255143000-7f7255145000  7f725536c000-7f725536d000  7f725536f000-7f725538b000  7f725558c000-7f725558d000
```

**Which files i need to copy knowing that both start from the same script and how to copy this state?**